# Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for

Tags: android, manifest, android-12

**Error:
Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.**

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.will_dev.vpn_app">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application
    android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.YouApplication"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.view.MainActivity"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.view.IntroActivity"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.Login"
       />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.TDView"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.EnterReferenceCode"
        />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.RewardPointClaim"
        />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.Verification"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.Spinner"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.AboutUs"
         />

    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.ContactUs"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.PrivacyPolice"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.Faq"
       />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.EarnPoint"
      />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.ForgetPassword"
        />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.Register"
       />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.SplashScreen"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.view.Servers"
        />
    <activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.fromanother.activity.WelcomeActivity"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="de.blinkt.openvpn.DisconnectVPNActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"

        android:noHistory="true"
        android:taskAffinity=".DisconnectVPN"
        android:theme="@style/blinkt.dialog" />

    <service
        android:name="de.blinkt.openvpn.core.OpenVPNService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.VpnService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity
        android:name="com.will_dev.vpn_app.view.PurchaseActivity"
         />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/admob_app_id" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

> i have added exported=true to launcher activity but still it failing

Answer (score 0):

Try add android: exported to all of your activities if you are targeting android 12. Even if you don't want to export it add android: export = "false".

Comment: i have tried this too but failed

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be with external libraries. Just wait when libraries will be updated or delete these libraries from project. Or you can try search in project and find which library uses intent. And use manifest merge attribute to add exported to external library.
https://android-doc.github.io/tools/building/manifest-merge.html